# How to tell custom developed magento block to use a template?

Tags: php, magento

This is the code in contollers

```
public function transactionsAction()
    {
        $ModelLayout = new Pteb_System_Model_Layout_Backend();
        $ModelLayout->LoadLayout();
        $Block = $ModelLayout->SetContentBlock( 'transactions-block', 'Pteb_System_Block_Cms' );
        $Block->setTemplate('user/transactions/results.phtml');
        $ModelLayout->ShowLayout();
    }
```

/* this is the content to display on the page, 
currently it displays without any template*/

```
$Block->setTemplate('user/transactions/results.phtml');
```

/* the template for the content above resides in the same folder as it is, with the name `form.phtml`. I replaced `results.phtml` with `form.phtml` in the above code but it displays the design only not the content.

Basically the `form.phtml` contains table structure with table heading while the `results.phtml` contains rows of contents.*/

**How do I tell this results.phtml to use form.phtml as a template?**

Comment: i suggest you to attach results.phtml and form.phtml with question

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to go to this block:

**Pteb_System_Block_Cms**

and add the following setTemplate script:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('abc/abc.phtml');
    }
```